# Boolean "Difference" producing artifacts

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier

I have a plain cube, and an object that was created by joining up several cubes.

[image: The two objects]

I then moved them to intersect:

[image]

Now I want to create a cutout, so the upper part can slide along the lower one. I added a boolean modifier and created a difference between the two, and expected to get a clean cutout that looks like a triangle from the side. Instead, I get lots of artifacts:

[image: Artifacts]

How can I fix this? I have uploaded my file here (containing only the two objects): http://www.wikifortio.com/737683/blender-problem-report.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Boolean isn't working *because* the cutter is made by joining up cubes. The surface isn't manifold. (i.e a single, watertight surface enclosing a continuous volume). Solid-geometry Booleans need unambiguously to be able to tell the difference between 'inside' and 'outside'.

You could remodel the cutter as a continuous extrusion. Here's one way, based on the existing geometry.

With Snap set to 'Vertex, and 'Active'. amd set Off, until activated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Duplicate the faces of one end, and <kbd>P</kbd> separate to a new object.

In Edit Mode's Header > Options, set *Automerge* on, and check 'Split Edges & Faces' .

Then you can unify the end-faces like this, with *Limited Dissolve*:

[image]

.. and <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the clean face, snapping to the old cutter.

[image]

Replace the old cutter with the new one in the  *Boolean* modifier, and the cut will be clean:

[image]